# Matlab - Extracting rows with specfic column value from table

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I'm trying to figure out how to extract rows from a table if a certain variable of a row has a certain value. I know how to do this in R but can't figure it out in Matlab. For example, let's say this is my table:

```
Var1    Var2    Var3
_____  _____   ______
 1.0    2.0   'class 1'
 1.1    2.1   'class 2'
 1.2    2.2   'class 3'
 1.3    2.3   'class 1'
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get all the rows where Var3 has the value "class 1". Concretely, I want this:

```
Var1    Var2    Var3
_____  _____   ______
 1.0    2.0   'class 1'
 1.3    2.3   'class 1'
```

So far, I've tried using a keyword argument, outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300187/matlab-extract-selected-rows-in-a-table-based-on-some-criterion), as well as using matlab rows to try and sort everything. Neither has worked.

Let's say T is my table. First, I tried

```
T(T.Var5 == 'class 1',:)
```

but got the error:

```
Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Then, I decided to get a little creative, and saw you could create row names in the Matlab documentation. So I did this:

```
A = T{:,{1:2}};
B = T{:,{3}};
B = table2array(B);
A.Properties.RowNames = B;
```

but I got the error:

```
Duplicate row name: 'class 1'.
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there an easy way to do this in Matlab?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`findgroups`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) to group your data.

For example:

```
a = [1.0; 1.1; 1.2; 1.3];
b = [2.0; 2.1; 2.2; 2.3];
c = {'class 1'; 'class 2'; 'class 3'; 'class 1'};
T = table(a, b, c);

[groupidx, group] = findgroups(T.c);
T_class1 = T(groupidx==1, :)
```

Which returns:

```
T_class1 =

  2×3 table

     a      b         c    
    ___    ___    _________

      1      2    'class 1'
    1.3    2.3    'class 1'
```

`findgroups` will return the group index of each row, along with an optional output of all the unique rows. In my example I'm assuming that `'class 1'` is the first output, but you can make the explicit comparison with `strcmp` to make a more robust solution.

Speaking of [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html), you can perform a similar indexing operation if you're looking for a specific string.

For example, you can do:

```
T_class1 = T(strcmp(T.c, 'class 1'), :)
```

Which also returns:

```
T_class1 =

  2×3 table

     a      b         c    
    ___    ___    _________

      1      2    'class 1'
    1.3    2.3    'class 1'
```

The advantage of `findgroups` is that it fits into a [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) workflow, allowing you to group and perform options on your table's data.

For example, we can find the mean of our `a` data by class in a few lines:

```
[groupidx, group] = findgroups(T.c);
mean_a = splitapply(@mean, T.a, groupidx);
outT = table(group, mean_a)
```

Which gives us:

```
outT =

  3×2 table

      group      mean_a
    _________    ______

    'class 1'    1.15  
    'class 2'     1.1  
    'class 3'     1.2
```

Comment: T_class1 = T(strcmp(T.c, 'class 1'), :) << this worked and is very simple. Thank you.